# Precision problem while evaluating RegionMember or Element in V10

Tags: version-10, precision-and-accuracy, regions

I'll try to give you a background on where the problem occured. The problem itself is defined near the end of the post.

I'm running a sort of a simulation of a particle in a box. I finally got my hands on Mathematica10 so I decided to use new built-in mechanisms such as regions.
Long story short: I need to determine the point at which the particle hits the bounding region.

I defined my box by:

```
{X, Y, Z} = {.05, .05, .3};
ip1 = InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, Y, 0}, {0, Y, Z}}];
ip2 = InfinitePlane[{{X, 0, 0}, {X, Y, 0}, {X, Y, Z}}];
ip3 = InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, 0}, {X, 0, 0}, {X, 0, Z}}];
ip4 = InfinitePlane[{{0, Y, 0}, {X, Y, 0}, {X, Y, Z}}];
ip5 = InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, Y, 0}, {X, Y, 0}}];
ip6 = InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, Z}, {0, Y, Z}, {X, Y, Z}}];
reg = RegionIntersection[Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {X, Y, Z}], RegionUnion[ip1, ip2, ip3, ip4, ip5, ip6]];
```

I generate the initial position and velocity of the particle as random numbers, then draw a `HalfLine` from the position of particle along the velocity vector. Finally, I check the intersection of the `HalfLine` and the bounding region `reg` with `RegionIntersection`.

Then I can extract the coordinates of the bouncing point and calculate the new velocity vector, define a new `HalfLine`, find the intersection, and so on...

**The Problem**

At some point, however, I get an error caused by the point not being a member (or element, both functions do the same in this case) of my bounding region (sounds ridiculously, because it's supposed to be the intersection of the region and the halfline).

When I print the coordinates of that point, I get:

```
In: p1
Out: {0.0000316867, 0.00969779, 0.3}
```

So everything looks fine, but doesn't work. I checked it with `Manipulate` - I entered these coordinates manually and `RegionMember[reg,{0.0000316867, 0.00969779, 0.3}]` evaluated to `True`.

Then I copied the coordinates of p1 from the output above and found out that they were in fact:

```
{0.00003168673646693154`, 0.009697790214128308`, 0.29999999999999993`}
```

The last coordinate was at fault. Is this a bug in the new functions? Any ideas how to get around it?

**EDIT: Computing p1:** @user21

```
line = HalfLine[r + v/10^8, v];
p1 = RegionBounds[RegionIntersection[line, reg]][[All, 1]];
```

If `line` would start on the wall, `RegionIntersection` would consist of two points. To avoid that, I translate the origin of the `HalfLine` along v a bit.

**EDIT 2: I've found a way around, but it doesn't answer the question about precision**

Okay, instead of defining `p1` as an element of `RegionBounds` I used `RegionCentroid`:

```
old: p1 = RegionBounds[RegionIntersection[line, reg]][[All, 1]];
new: p1 = RegionCentroid[RegionIntersection[line, reg]]
```

And it seems to have solved the problem.
But I have no idea why, because for a single point both `RegionCentroid` and `RegionBounds` should give the same result.

I tried both functions on a "buggy" (i.e. found by `RegionBounds`) point and here's what I got:

```
In: RegionBounds[RegionIntersection[line, reg]]
Out: {{0.0494424, 0.0494424}, {0.0341449, 0.0341449}, {0.3, 0.3}}
```

And after copy-pasting the output:

```
{{0.04944240524519992`, 0.04944240524519992`}, {0.03414494309476567`, 0.03414494309476567`}, {0.30000000000000004`, 0.30000000000000004`}}
```

And for RegionCentroid:

```
In: RegionCentroid[RegionIntersection[line, reg]]
Out: {0.0494424, 0.0341449, 0.3}
```

Copy & paste:

```
{0.04944240524519991`, 0.03414494309476552`, 0.3`}
```

Well, I can imagine that it's due to internal functions used, but I'm still somehow confused that the results do not "converge" for this case.

Comment: how did you compute p1?

Comment: @user21 I added this information to the post.

Comment: What are `r` and `v`? You could use exact arithmetic with `Rationalize[{.05, .05, .3}]` and making sure `r` and `v` are exact too.

Comment: `r` and `v` are the coords and the velocity of my particle, respectively. I will try that and see what happens. Thank you!